# Сравнить 2 текстовых файла

Tags: c#

Есть 2 текстовых файла и надо вывести индексы всех строк, где есть отличия

Проблема моего кода:

Формат вывода не тот. Хотел сделать, чтобы выводилось не слово которое отличается, а именно номер строки которая отличается.

Например: текст в 1 файле `"Hello world"`, а во 2-м файле `"Hello"`

И я хочу чтобы вместо `world`, вывелось `"изменения в 1 строчке"`

Мой код:

```
public List<string> Diff()
{
    var lines1 = File.ReadAllLines(_test1).ToArray();
    var lines2 = File.ReadAllLines(_test2).ToArray();
            
    var symDiff = lines1.Except(lines2).Union(lines2.Except(lines1)).ToList();

    return symDiff;
}
```

Comment: Отлично!)) Теперь скажите в чем конкретно проблема? Выводится не то, что вы ожидали или выдает ошибку? В любом случае лучше привести минимальный пример, который можно было бы запустить у себя.

Comment: формат вывода не тот( хотел сделать что вывело не слово которое отличается ,а именно номер строки которая отличается

ну например текст в 1 файле "Hello world"
а во 2-м файле "Hello"
и я хочу вместо того что бы вывело не world а
просто "изменения в 1 строчке"

Comment: Пожалуйста занесите все это в сам вопрос нажав на кнопку "Править" под вопросом

Comment: [дубликат?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/868589/179763)

Comment: @tym32167 не совсем, автору требуется получить индексы различных строк

Comment: тогда это вопрос простого цикла по коллекциям

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq вариант (не проверял, проверяйте сами, но идея ясна)

```
public List<string> Diff()
{
    var lines1 = File.ReadAllLines(_test1);
    var lines2 = File.ReadAllLines(_test2); 
    
    return lines1.Zip(lines2, (x,y)=>(x,y))
        .Select((item, i) => (item, i))
        .Where(x=> string.CompareOrdinal( x.item.x, x.item.y) != 0)
        .Select(x=>$"изменения в {x.i + 1} строчке")
        .ToList();  
}
```

Comment: `ReadLines` возвращает `IEnumerable<string>`, кстати, может это повод улучшить ответ с точки зрения прожорливости в отношении оперативы :) А `ReadAllLines` возвращает `string[]`.

Comment: @aepot почему бы и нет, хотя это решает проблему, которой у автора вопроса нет :)

Comment: `ReadAllLines` надежнее в плане файл будет вычитан полностью и гарантированно закрыт, в то время как у `ReadLines` могут быть нюансы, если вычитывать не до конца. Так что это из разряда "а еще вот так вот можно".

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант

```
var lines1 = File.ReadAllLines(_test1);
var lines2 = File.ReadAllLines(_test2);

var len = Math.Max(lines1.Length, lines2.Length);

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    if (lines1.Length <= i || lines2.Length <= i || string.CompareOrdinal(lines1[i], lines2[i]) != 0)
        Console.WriteLine($"изменения в {i + 1} строчке");
```