# Проблема с написанием программы для проверки орфографии на c#

Tags: c#, проверка

Имеется код, представляющий из себя словарь и цикл. Принцип работы прост: вводится слово из словаря с ОДНОЙ ошибкой, а благодаря циклу выводится правильное написание данного слова из того же словаря.
Так вот проблема как раз в том, что слово проверятся если в нем допущена лишь **одна** ошибка, и если длина слова совпадает с длиной правильного варианта его написания (например, слово програма с одной "м" не будет засчитано за ошибку). Прошу помочь сделать так, чтоб программа так же исправляла слова с более чем одной ошибкой, а так же исправляла слова, длина которых не идентична длине правильной вариации написания данного слова. Вот сам код:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] slovar = {"Здравствуйте","вот","моя","программа",
 "предназначенная","для","проверки","орфографии","в",
 "тексте","состоящем","из","заданного","набора","слов",
 "шла","Саша","по","шоссе","так","же","дабы","словарь","казался","больше","добавим","ещё","парочку"};


        Console.WriteLine("Введите слово из словаря(с ошибкой):");
        string s = Console.ReadLine();

        var closestWords = slovar
            .Select(x => new { orig = s, dict = x, Distance = Diff(x, s) })
            .GroupBy(x => x.Distance)
            .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
            .Take(1)
            .SelectMany(x => x.Select(z => z.dict))
            .ToArray();

        Console.WriteLine("Вы ввели {s}");
        Console.WriteLine("Самые близкие слова {string.Join(" ,", closestWords)}");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы можете отредактировать пост - кнопка Править.

Comment: Можно посмотреть в сторону [расстояния Левенштейна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0)

Comment: ассоциация https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1276238/179763

Comment: @aepot оно вроде и так и так связывается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще, для получения разницы строк есть алгоритмы, такие как [расстояние Левенштейна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0). Такой алгоритм относительно легко позволяет найти разнницу между строками ([да и между чем угодно другим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/868766/179763), что можно сравнить).

Пример нахождения расстояния между строками

```
private static int Diff(string original, string actual)
{
    var board = new int[original.Length + 1, actual.Length + 1];
    for (var i = 0; i < board.GetLength(0); i++) board[i, 0] = i;
    for (var i = 0; i < board.GetLength(1); i++) board[0, i] = i;

    for (var i = 1; i < board.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (var j = 1; j < board.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            var stringsEquals = original[i - 1] == actual[j - 1];
            var add = (stringsEquals ? 0 : 1);
            board[i, j] = Math.Min(board[i - 1, j - 1] + add * 2, Math.Min(board[i - 1, j] + 1, board[i, j - 1] + 1));
        }
    }
    return board[original.Length, actual.Length];
}
```

Ваша код можно обновить так

```
string[] slovar = {"Здравствуйте","вот","моя","программа",
     "предназначенная","для","проверки","орфографии","в",
     "тексте","состоящем","из","заданного","набора","слов",
     "шла","Саша","по","шоссе","так","же","дабы","словарь","казался","больше","добавим","ещё","парочку"};


Console.WriteLine("Введите слово из словаря(с ошибкой):");
string s = Console.ReadLine();

var closestWords = slovar
    .Select(x => new { orig = s, dict = x, Distance = Diff(x, s)})
    .GroupBy(x=>x.Distance)
    .OrderBy(x=>x.Key)
    .Take(1)        
    .SelectMany(x=>x.Select(z=>z.dict))
    .ToArray();

Console.WriteLine($"Вы ввели {s}");
Console.WriteLine($"Самые близкие слова {string.Join(" ,", closestWords)}");

Console.ReadLine();
```

Проверка

```
Введите слово из словаря(с ошибкой):
Вы ввели Зраствуй
Самые близкие слова Здравствуйте
```

Вам соталось определить какие то ещё критерии для похожести строк, если вы хотите лучше результат, так как сейчас он только вычисляет расстояние, не более того.

Как пример о чем я говорю,

```
Введите слово из словаря(с ошибкой):
Вы ввели Здрасти
Самые близкие слова Здравствуйте, из, дабы
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/125024/discussion-on-answer-by-tym32167-------).

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
```

using System.Linq;

namespace disa
{
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
string[] slovar = {"Здравствуйте","вот","моя","программа",
"предназначенная","для","проверки","орфографии","в",
"тексте","состоящем","из","заданного","набора","слов",
"шла","Саша","по","шоссе","так","же","дабы","словарь","казался","больше","добавим","ещё","парочку"};

```
        Console.WriteLine("Введите слово из словаря(с ошибкой):");
        string s = Console.ReadLine();

        var closestWords = slovar
            .Select(x => new { orig = s, dict = x, Distance = Diff(x, s) })
            .GroupBy(x => x.Distance)
            .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
            .Take(1)
            .SelectMany(x => x.Select(z => z.dict))
            .ToArray();

        Console.WriteLine("Вы ввели {s}");
        Console.WriteLine("Самые близкие слова {string.Join(" ,", closestWords)}");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}