# Как называются алгоритмы, пошагово показывающие изменение слова?

Tags: алгоритм

Нужен путь преобразования одного слова в другое по шагам, например: `емтто - метто - метро`. Интуитивно догадываюсь, что это что-то из области расстояния редактирования (Дамерау-Левенштейна, операции перестановки тоже нужны), но не понимаю как переложить матрицу оттуда на изменения слова. Как такие алгоритмы называются?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1276250/179763 ?

Answer (score 0):

Когда вы рассчитали расстояние редактирования с помощью алгоритма Дамерау-Левенштейна, то получили матрицу, в последней ячейке которой лежит расстояние редактирования.

Вам нужно получить путь, по которому пришли в данную ячейку, а это проще всего делать, по ходу построения матрицы (при определении минимума в текущей ячейке) записывая дополнительную информацию - из какой ячейки пришли в данную, какую операцию использовали

Имея такую информацию (в той же таблице как дополнительные поля, или в дополнительной таблице), раскручиваете путь из последней ячейки к началу и потом инвертируете его.

Что касается названия - специального имени, наверное, нет - алгоритмы восстановления пути

Comment: дубликат? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1276250/179763

Comment: @tym32167 Сам по себе вопрос - не дубликат, но ваше решение содержит "бонус"

Comment: Ну пущай просто ссылка тогда висит - автор захочет - заглянет