# Изучение низкоуровневого программирования

Tags: книги, железо, embedded, системное-программирование

Учусь в универе на 2-ом курсе на IT направлении.
Посоветуйте с чего начать знакомство с железом, драйверами под железо, где почитать про разные ОС, микроконтроллеры, архитектуры. Короче всё что связанно с железом и где я с этим могу работать.
Программировал на ассемблере(NASM,TASM), немного C++(под STM в IAR) и немного arduino

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454683/213987

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Современный embedded это очень широкий спектр задач, начинающийся с разработки и тестирования PCB и заканчивающийся в юзерспейсе операционных систем и бэкэнде веб сервисов (спасибо IoT за это). Без дополнительных уточнений, адекватного ответа на вопрос дать невозможно.

Студенту второго курса однако будет полезно знать что в embedded целый зоопарк архитектур, спецификаций, операционных систем... и в любой компании придётся учится новому. В связи с этим посоветую не заострять внимание на ассемблерах или архитектурах а учить более общие вещи. Электроника (хотя бы на базовом уровне), базовые компоненты MCU и периферия, операционные системы (Linux и RTOS), С (обязательно), Python (желательно), устройство компьютерных сетей, протоколы беспроводной связи, алгоритмы и структуры данных (в embedded всё ещё актуально знать как оно работает), DSP....

Достаточно полные и легкочитаемые справочники по Компьютерной архитектуре, Сетям и Операционным системам написал **Эндрю Таненбаум**.
RTOS можно пощупать на примере FreeRTOS (запускается под Ардуино) по [статьям](http://easyelectronics.ru/img/ARM_kurs/FreeRTOS/Kurniz.pdf) **Андрея Курница**. Для остального есть официальные спецификации и/или старые зарекомендовавшие себя книги (в мире embedded они не скоро устареют).

Comment: Спасибо большое, уже есть хоть какой-то старт. Вот из-за такого зоопарка и возникает неразбериха с тем, чтобы выбрать более узконаправленный спектр)