# Книги и учебные ресурсы по проектированию БД: SQL && NoSQL

Tags: sql, база-данных, книги, nosql

Рекомендуемая литература, учебники и документация по проектированию БД: SQL && NoSQL

Формат:

> Имя Фамилия — «Название книги целиком и полностью», ГГГГ г..

Формат для переведенной литературы:

> Имя Фамилия (Name Surname) — «Название книги целиком и полностью», ГГГГ перевода ("Full name of the book", YYYY )

- Не создавайте новых ответов — редактируйте этот.
- Старайтесь сохранять разделение по категориям (когда они будут).
- Сохраняйте алфавитную (лексикографическую) сортировку по названию книги.
- Пожалуйста,

  - не размещайте ссылки на нелегальный контент вроде торрент-трекеров.

---

П.С.: захотелось почитать материал по теме, но на ресурсе не оказалось  такой темы, при том что, такие вопросы появляются довольно часто.

Comment: Так JavaScript или sql?

Comment: @VladSpirin, можно, но мне нечего туда поместить. Я еще ничего не прочитал, чтобы иметь возможность рекомендовать

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Общая теория по SQL

- [Основы современных баз данных](http://citforum.ru/database/osbd/contents.shtml) - С.Д. Кузнецов,
  информационно-аналитические материалы Центра Информационных
  Технологий

## Microsoft SQL Server и Transact-SQL

**Книги для новичков**

- Ицик Бен-Ган, Деян Сарка, Рон Талмейдж (Itzik Ben-Gan, Dejan Sarka,
  Ron Talmage) — "Microsoft SQL Server 2012. Создание запросов.", 2014
  г. ("Querying Microsoft SQL Server 2012", 2012). ISBN: 978-5-7502-0432-8 (перевод), 978-0-7356-6604-7 (оригинал). Хорошая книга для изучения Transact-SQL с нуля. В книге описаны и объяснены все основные конструкции языка.
- Ицик Бен-Ган, Деян Сарка, Рон Талмейдж (Itzik Ben-Gan, Dejan Sarka,
  Ron Talmage) — "Microsoft SQL Server 2012. Реализация хранилищ данных.", 2014
  г. ("Implementing a Data Warehouse with Microsoft SQL Server 2012", 2012). ISBN: 978-5-7502-0431-1 (перевод), 978-0-7356-6609-2 (оригинал).
- Ицик Бен-Ган (Itzik Ben-Gan) — "Microsoft SQL Server 2012. Высокопроизводительный код T-SQL. Оконные функции", 2013
  г. ("Microsoft SQL Server 2012: High-Performance T-SQL: Using Window Functions", 2013). ISBN: 978-5-7502-0416-8 (перевод). **Must Read книга для любого разработчика, который так или иначе работает с базами данных.** Книга содержит большое количество примеров реализации типовых задач таких как поиск пробелов или островков в наборах.

**Книги для специалистов: внутренняя "кухня"**

- Dmitri Korotkevitch - "Pro SQL Server Internals 2nd ed. Edition", 2016. ISBN: 9781484219638. Издана пока только на английском языке. В книге автор подробно рассказывает о внутреннем устройстве SQL Server и дает достаточно подробные описания того как database engine выполняет запросы на внутреннем уровне. Книга будет полезна разработчикам, которым важно понимать как все устроено изнутри.
- Kalen Delaney - "SQL Server Concurrency. Locking, Blocking and Row Versioning", 2012. ISBN: 978-1-906434-90-8. Издана только на английском. В книге автор подробно рассказывает про транзакции, уровни изоляции транзакций, блокировки и их типы.

**Документация Microsoft**

- [Документация по Microsoft SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/?view=sql-server-ver16)

## PostgreSQL

- [Документация от Postgres Professional](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql)

## NoSQL

- Раздел еще не написан

---

## Проверка запросов онлайн

- [SQL Server; Postgres; MySQL; Oracle; SQLite; MariaDB; Db2; Firebird; Node.js; YugabyteDB](https://dbfiddle.uk/)
- [MS SQL Server 2017; Postgres 9.3 - 9.6; MySQL 5.6; Oracle 11g; SQLite WebSQL, SQL.js](http://sqlfiddle.com/)
- [SQLize Online / PHPize Online: SMS SQL Server 2017 - 2022; Postgres 11 - 15; MySQL 5.7 - 8; Oracle 19 - 23; SQLite 3; MariaDB 10; SOQOL (beta)](https://sqlize.online/)
- [Postgres 9.4 - 15; MySQL 5.5 - 8; SQLite 3.26 - 3.39](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)
- [MySQL 5.6; Oracle 11g; MS SQL Server 2019](https://sqltest.net/)