# Как читать книги из официального справочника литературы

Tags: книги

Хотелось бы узнать, каким образом читать книги в официальном справочнике литературы [Книги и другие материалы для обучения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683) .Например, в разделе "Для начинающих" по литературе C# есть несколько книг, и, чтобы освоить все базовые вещи языка, я должен прочитать всю указанную литературу или достаточно одной книги из раздела?

Comment: `или достаточно одной книги из раздела?`     Достаточно одного предложения :)

Comment: Ну это зависит от того как вы воспринимаете материал. Прочитайте одну и пробуйте что нибудь написать. Если чувствуете что не хватает каких то базовых знаний попробуйте другую

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть определенные авторы, которые довольно таки популярны, за счет своего перевода, полезного материала и его подачи. Можете начать с них. (Например Герберт Шилдт)

Так же книги располагаются по своей сложности, естественно, если вы не читали более простую(базовую литературу), то вы просто не поймете ничего из написанного из более высокой.

Есть так же много одинаковых книг из одного уровня обучения(например, начального), их просто полным полно, и у каждого автора там естественно, встречается множество материала, что есть и у других, поэтому тоже ,как раз и советую читать популярных авторов, у них достаточно объемные и ресурсоемкие материалы, а потом сразу, после прочтения таких материалов, сможете уже многое осилить из уровня повыше.

Так же советую смотреть книги по оптимизации кода, паттернам, принципам программирования(SOLID,YAGNI и т.д.), не плохая часть - вопросы с собеседований по вашему языку(оттуда многое набрал). Это довольно таки важно.

На начальном уровне можно прочитать какую нибуть одну - две объемные книги,  а после, по мере поступления информации, сами будете понимать , что вам нужно, а вам нужно то, чего вы не знаете, ибо расширенный арсенал - всегда отлично. Разные способы решений, меньше костылей и тд.

Примерный путь: 
1)

C# 4.0: полное руководство, Герберт Шилдт.

HeadFirst C# (если не понятнен C# 4.0: полное руководство, Герберт Шилдт.)

(Можно выбирать другие варианты , в зависимости от того, какого популярного автора вы выбрали)
2)

Вопросы и ответы с собеседований по C#(помогло мне расширить кругозор, пришло понимание что учить дальше и в какую сторону двигаться, разбираются базовые детали, которые были не до конца понятны)

3)

Было бы не плохо почитать про книги по оптимизации кода, паттернам, принципам программирования(SOLID,YAGNI и т.д.) - это спрашивают на собеседованиях в том числе и так же must have. После - углубление в основы языка и усвоение точких моментов.(читайте книги уровня по выше по той же тактике)

4)

Вы знаете основы языка, умеете делать не плохой каркас приложений и писать более менее код, определитесь с конкретным направлением, точнее чем хотете заниматься конкретно, а дальше все по накатанной - популярная книга для начинающих и постепенное углубление в эту тема, читая книги,кодя, ища различные вопросы на тонкие темы программирования

Во время этого, постепенно, вы сами сможете определить , что изучать и куда идти, так как будете понимать какие пути существуют и что с этим всем делать :)

В КОММЕНТАРИЯХ ПОЛЕЗНЫЕ РЕКОМЕНДАЦИИ !!!

Удачи в изучении !

Алгоритм применим не только к C# , но и вполне подойдет для других языков.

Пишите в комментариях - что еще можно порекомендовать )

Comment: Как ни странно это прозвучит, я бы посоветовал для начала прочесть [K&R](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%A1%D0%B8_(%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0)), поскольку все остальные, как императивные, так и ООП языки лишь расширяют эту модель вычислений.