# <div> или стандарт?

Tags: html, вёрстка

Недавно начал изучать `HTML` и уже 3 сайта написал (списывал проекты с ютуба и разбирал код). Везде видел `<div> <div>` вместо `<header> <footer>` и тд. И вроде как позиционируют себя каналы это школы программирования либо какой-то хороший разработчик.

Объясните как правильно верстать пожалуйста

Comment: https://webref.ru/

Comment: @MaximLensky ???

Comment: ссылочку откройте ...там это всё описано - специально для тех кому интересно

Comment: @MaximLensky где? Вы можете прямую ссылку скинуть?

Comment: Можно верстать все блоки тэгом `<div>`, но есть такое понятие как семантика, это понятие относиться к SEO.
Подробнее можете почитать тут - https://webref.ru/course/html-basics/semantics

Comment: я искать не хочу так как лень - вы читайте от первой страницы и до последней ... а если коротко и по сути - то DIV это универсальный тег и на все случаи жизни тегов не существует и потому разметку можно делать на html5 тегах а вот внутри уже делать на DIV а можно и всё делать на div

Comment: @ANYWAYCODE Ну получается лучше использовать семантику т.к на SEO влияет правильно?

Comment: @MikeMclaren да, всё верно, заголовки в <h1-h6>, параграфы в <p> и любые другие текстовые теги, шапка в <header>, футер в <footer>, статья в <article>.
А так же на странице может быть несколько <header>,<footer>, потому что у статьи есть шапка и футер, как правило - заголовок, автор, дата и прочая информация, по типу поделиться, понравилось и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Семантическая вёрстка правильнее, но теоретическая правильность быстро разбивается о суровую практику.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Особенно, если разметка генерируется шаблонизатором.

Comment: Семантическая вёрстка правильнее, но теоретическая правильность быстро разбивается о суровую практику. Если честно я вот в этом предложении запутался :D. Я новичок, как понять разбивается о суровую практику?)

Comment: Это значит, что реальные проекты очень тяжело верстать без использования пирамид из div'ов. Попробуйте сами написать более-менее серьёзный сайт и быстро всё поймёте.

Comment: Хорошо спасибо!

Comment: Ну <header> <footer> можно же написать, а внутри всё div'aми? Или даже <header> и <footer> на практике всё равно превращаются в пирамиды div'oв?

Comment: Можно. Не превращаются. Просто они относительно недавно появились и к ним не все ещё привыкли.

Comment: Кстати, видео-уроки в подавляющем большинстве случае очень низкокачественные. Лучше учиться по учебникам.

Comment: Не подскажете какие учебники?

Comment: [Книги и другие материалы для обучения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454683/204271)