# Посоветуйте материалы для самостоятельного освоения Computer Science

Tags: информатика

Хочу самостоятельно освоить Computer Science. Ознакомился со статьёй на tproger (https://tproger.ru/curriculum/computer-science-step-by-step/) разобрал все книги кроме первой (очень тяжело идёт её чтение т.к. довольно сложно написана). Хочу узнать больше.

Comment: Computer Science - это информатика по-русски, огромная научная область и книги можно перечислять очень долго по разным направлениям развития. [Тут есть сборник книг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683/) в том числе и по фундаментальным знаниям. Вас интересует конкретная область баз данных или вы просто так тег поставили? В базах данных как я помню основной труд был Коннолли Т., Бегг К. "Базы данных. Проектирование, реализация и сопровождение. Теория и практика.". (читается сложно) Хотя может есть что-то лучше. Ну и практика использования конкретных баз данных.

Comment: Терзайте Танненбаума, Вирта, Дейта и Мартина.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и другие материалы для обучения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Answer (score 0):

Все хорошие книги написаны сложным языком, для получения фундаментальных знаний лучше пройти онлайн-курсы на образовательных платформах. После этого можно уже читать книги для прокачки вглубь.

Вперед на сайты - [Stepic](https://stepik.org/catalog?language=ru&tag=22872), [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/browse), [OpenEdu](https://openedu.ru/course/#group=26).