# Практика VS Теория в программировании

Tags: javascript, php, html, веб-программирование, сss3

Занимаюсь web программированием вот уже полтора года.

Всё это время **уделял примерно 5ч в день** на изучение. **Переписывал** нужную **информацию** в тетрадь, затем **учил** - после **практиковал**.

Из которых **4ч** - теория, **1ч** - практика.

На каждом этапе понимал, что постоянно **что - то забываю**. Как **мне кажется** необходимо что - то поменять.

Может быть кто - то сталкивался с подобными проблемами. Если так, то **жду ответов !!!**

*P.s. //  Регулярно повторяю старое, нахожу новое, учу, практикую.*

Comment: Что означает «теория» в данном контексте?

Comment: Повторение старого, изучение и повторение нового материала

Comment: Можно поконкретнее? Вы книги читаете? Какие (укажите названия и авторов)?

Comment: Изучал css и html в связке на ресурсе webref.ru 

В данный момент учу JavaScript на learn.javascript.ru

Также были совсем незначительные и многочисленные дополнения ( вроде GitHub )

Comment: вопрос вне тематики ресурса

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 4ч - теория, 1ч - практика.

Это не очень хорошо. Знания нужно закреплять, для этого их нужно практиковать как можно чаще.

Конструкции языка программирования и стандартные функции «зубрить» не обязательно (кроме случаев когда нужно сдать какой-либо экзамен). Приемы, которые используются часто, дорабатываются до автоматизма на практике. То, что используется редко, можно по необходимости найти в документации/интернете: при наличии базовых знаний это не должно быть сложно.

Как правило, люди учатся «наоборот»: сначала читают основы, потом работают несколько лет, совершают кучу ошибок, после перечитывают основы и только тогда начинают что-то понимать. Попробуйте и Вы так же: пройдите курс онлайн, попрактикуйтесь несколько недель и потом пройдите его заново.

Что еще можно попробовать:

- поставить себе цель с критериями успеха (устроиться на работу, написать свой сайт и т.п.);
- поискать курсы с большим количеством практики, желательно с построением рабочих сайтов (не знаю какие у Вас цели, для примера нашел в интернете [специализацию Яндекса по фронтенду на coursera](https://www.coursera.org/specializations/razrabotka-interfeysov));
- писать как можно больше кода (попробуйте копировать реальные сайты, которыми пользуетесь);
- читать [книги](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F): обычно в книгах материал разбирается более подробно;
- отвечать на вопросы на Stack Overflow: тут много вопросов от новичков, на которых можно «набить руку»;
- записаться на обучение оффлайн или наняться куда-нибудь стажером.

Comment: Можете уточнить ? В каком соотношении ( практика / теория ) лучше всего можно было бы развиваться в моём случае ( 5ч.) ?

Comment: @ВикторСавченко В ответе я предложил схему со сконцентированными периодами «несколько дней обучения — несколько недель практики». Есть и другие варианты: можно постоянно практиковаться и изучать материалы по мере необходимости, на стажировке или платном курсе будет свое расписание. P.S. Теорией обычной называют научные основы (алгоритмы, структуры данных, дискретная математика и т.п.).

Answer (score 2):

> Всё это время уделял примерно 5ч в день на изучение. Переписывал
>   нужную информацию в тетрадь, затем учил - после практиковал.

Как говорил в своё время С. Джобс: "Работать нужно не 12 часов в день, а головой!".

Заниматься зубрёжкой в программировании, если Вы не студент и Вам не нужно сдавать экзамены, бесполезно. Вам нужно просто разобраться что и как работает и почему это так.

Тогда у Вас дело пойдёт.

> постоянно что - то забываю

Это не страшно. Даже опытные программисты могут что-то забыть, если давно не использовали. Но, если до этого была практика и есть понимание принципа работы обычно можно легко вспомнить забытое или найти его описание, чтобы освежить в памяти.

Comment: Если не трудно, могли бы уточнить .

То есть я могу вообще забыть про повторение изученного и просто учить новое и практиковать ?

Comment: @ВикторСавченко, ваша проблема в том, что Вы пытаетесь зубрить, а не изучать. Изучить это не только прочитать, но в первую очередь понять как и почему это так работает (я уже писал в ответе). Главное не то, сколько Вы заучили, а то насколько Вы умеете этим пользоваться. При желании можно выучит наизусть не один и не два учебника, но если при этом нет понимания как правильно применить эти знания, толку от такой учёбы "ноль". Просто зря потраченное время.