# Какую книгу c# выбрать для профессианального уровня?

Tags: c#, wpf

Собственно, вопрос с заголовке. Хочу узнать как грамотно строить архитектуру приложения, какими способами, тонкости языка, как лучше писать код, как строить большие приложения и т.п.

Лучше если будет перевод т.к. на англ читаю с небольшим пингом и осознается он чуть дольше, но если книга действительно хорошая то и на английском пойдет

Comment: нет такой книги в природе, а если бы была, была бы она страниц на 100 000. Будьте более конкртетны в том, что именно вам надо улучшить.

Comment: темы `как грамотно строить архитектуру приложения`, `как лучше писать код`, `как строить большие приложения` по сути вообще не относятся к C#

Comment: Если речь о WPF, то изучите MVVM. Посмотрите популярные пакеты NuGet. Узнайте, какие вопросы задают на собеседованиях программистам, найдите на них ответы. Сдайте несколько бесплатных тестов на [GeekBrains](https://geekbrains.ru/), проверьте свои навыки. Затыкание таким образом дыр в знаниях и практика, поднимет ваш уровень. И изучите ООП и паттерны на его основе, даже начните с этого.

Comment: Ну список книг по C# и фундаментальным знаниям у нас есть: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683/Книги-и-другие-материалы-для-обучения А вот с научиться писать код, строить большие приложения и т.п. уже сложнее и решается опытом, в большей части своим и в меньшей чтением литературы.

Comment: Фундаментальные уже давно есть, недавно стал писать большой проект и понял, что лажаю с архитектурой и даже не знаю, как исправить это. Можете подсказать репозитории больших проектов по шарпу где вы можете сказать что да, тут построено грамотно. Под большим я подразумеваю что-то на уровне VS, 3D max, UE4, фотошоп

Comment: Строить большие долгоживующие приложения невозможно без модульного тестирования. Поэтому обязательно читайте книгу **The art of unit testing** (второе издание). Модульные тесты невозможно или очень сложно писать, если код сильно связан. Поэтому обязательна к прочтению книга **Dependency Injection in .NET**. Инъекция зависимостей позволит писать слабосвязанный код. Это положительно скажется на всей архитектуре.