# Чисты код и архитектура

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

задумался сделать большой проект для резюме.
Сам проект это приложение для контроля рабочих:

1. Просмотр з/п у рабочих
2. Изминения з/п и премий
3. Добавления задач
4. Просмотр задач, з/п, запрос на отпуск и повышения з/п
5. Добавление рабочих
6. Каждый рабочий имеет свой уровень доступа к информации

Стак технологий: Java, H2, Spring

Учусь на 2 курсе.

И собственно вопрос, как правильно заложить архитектуру такого приложения, до этого делал в основном приложения с уроков или в универ

Делаю приложения для резюме и чтобы научится спринга ну и повысить свой уровень в джаве.
Рассчитываю что проект займет около 1-2 месяца, возможно Вы можете подсказать что ещё добавить.

Comment: Логирование, Security

Comment: Вы берете сильно много на себя. Возьмите маленький проект. Например, просто трекер задач. И сделайте его хорошо. Лучше что то одно сделать хорошо, чем 10 вещей сделать плохо.

Comment: Трекер задач делал на занятия с программирования, в этом проекте хочу научится именно спринга. Очень хочу сам дорасти до уровня Junior Java(или близко). Хочу работать, но к сожалению на стажировку нет вакансий, даже бесплатных нету.

Comment: Если к кому то обращаетесь, указывайте ник вот так @Vadym. Не знаю, какой вы трекер делали, но наверное что то близкое к ToDo листу. Попробуйте развить идею, организовать задачи в проекты, в доски, в каледнарное прдеставление, в диграмму ганта, отлложенные задачи, задачи с комментариями, многопользовательские проекты, разграничение прав юзеров, отледвание произаодительности юзеров\команд\проектов, интеграция с какой нибудь системой типа кадров или jira, в общем тут полет фантазии и ничего не мешает все это написать на spring

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо большое

Comment: На здоровье, успехов!

Comment: @tym32167 можете порекомендовать статьи/книги о том как правильно заложить архитектуру (сейчас читаю чистый код и чистая архитектура) и как вообще показать что я что-то умею

Comment: Фаулер - Шаблоны корпоративных приложений. Классическая книга для начинающих. Она, правда, немного устарела, но для небольших проектов в самый раз. Она не привязана ни к языку, ни к платформе, то есть чтобы книгу понять - надо идеи из неё покодить на практике, чтобы покодить - придется хорошо подумать.

Comment: Также у нас есть сборники книг [Книги и другие материалы для обучения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454683/179763)