# СОВРЕМЕННЫЕ книги по C# для новичков

Tags: c#

Большинство известных книг для начинающих 13-15 года, актуальны ли они или имеет смысл поискать что-то более свежее?
И если стоит то подскажите какие?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-c

Comment: А вот еще материалы для обучения (чтобы потом не делали еще вопросы): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f/454684#454684

Comment: @Aarnihauta это как раз ссылка на книги о которых я говорил 14 годов, а я хочу найти именно свежие

Comment: C# in a nutshell, там до C# 9 включительно, но еще есть метанит и codeblog на ютубе

Comment: Для начинающих и старых книг хватит, если смотреть внутренности языка, новые фичи можно потом доизучить. Вот интерфейс, если идти дальше консоли, наверное лучше в старых книгах не смотреть.