# Книги о современном C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Подскажите, какие существуют книги на русском языке по C# 10 (.Net 6) или C# 9 (.Net 5) для относительно начинающего в языке (разобраться), но опыт на других языках имеется (Java). Имеет ли смысл читать старые книги где еще .Net Framework ?

Из последнего нашел:
Язык программирования C# 9 и платформа .NET 5. Основные принципы и практики программирования. 10-е издание

Есть мнение по ней?

Comment: Дубликат вопроса [СОВРЕМЕННЫЕ книги по C# для новичков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1372288) (который в свою очередь дубликат вопроса [Книги и учебные ресурсы по C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть прекрасная (и единственная на русском языке) книжка по C# 9.0 нашего любимого Албахари:

"Джозеф Албахари: C# 9.0. Справочник. Полное описание языка"

[image: албахари]

Появилась она совсем недавно, буквально месяца три назад.

По десятому C# - не перевели еще...

Но всё не так уж плохо. Есть ряд отличий в NET Core 6 от NET Core 5, но про них можно прочитать в сконцентрированном виде, потому что платформа уже достаточно разгналась, и регулярная работа по популяризации всего, происходящего "на переднем крае" - ведётся. Другое дело, что "исходниками" будут, конечно же, англоязычные ресурсы.

А по NET Core 5 - можно читать того же Албахари, он пишет весьма хорошо. По моему, опыта в Java достатчоно, чтобы читать по C# буквально что угодно, и "въезжать" достаточно быстро.

Имеет ли смысл читать более ранние книги, например по C# 6.0? Не очень простой вопрос. С одной стороны, 60-70% информации, содержащейся в книге того же Албахари по C# 6.0 (я просто их обе читал, поэтому и говорю на их примере)
абсолютно применимо и к C# 9.0. С другой стороны, если есть более свежая информация - поему бы не воспользоваться сразу ей?

Но я не хочу, чтобы мой ответ выглядел как реклама конкретной книги. Просто с ней я знаком, и о её достоинствах могу говорить.

Comment: Подскажите, от этого автора есть книга C# 9 Карманный справочник, стоит дешевле, не знаете хорошая или нет?

Comment: насколько я могу судить по предыдущему изданию "карманного справочника" - это именно справочник... То есть., если есть желание разобраться в языке - я бы купил "полную версию", ттам всё таки много вещей написано так, что экономится время на поиск инфы.

Comment: А "полная" версия тоже ведь справочник называется. Она подойдет для обучения? Если да, думаю именно над этим вариантом тогда, спасибо.

Comment: Да, разница только в том, что первая книжка - это "C# 9.0. Карманный справочник" (и весит она 200 грамм, в мягкой обложке), а вторая- "C# 9.0. Справочник. Полное описание языка", и весит она уже полкило. Но это - больше тысячи старниц довольно увлекательного чтива! И по моему, вполне подходящего для глубокого обучения языку. (и я, в отличие от продавцов, материально не заинтересован :-) )