# Кто нибудь помнит название сайта с собраной документацией по множеству языков?

Tags: документация

Когда то наткнулся на несколько ресурсов где были собраны документации по множеству из общеизвестных языках и фреймворках, несколько недель уже не могу его найти при том что тогда попадались и аналоги

Помню что основное меню было слева со списком всех языков и фреймворков с иконками

Comment: [оно?](https://metanit.com/) или может [это](https://professorweb.ru/)?

Comment: К сожалению нет, хотя за вторую ссылку благодарю

Comment: Возможно имеет смысл закрыть как дубликат этого вопроса: [Книги и другие материалы для обучения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454683/1365)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Ссылки на документации разных языков программирования

Сайты [Metanit](https://metanit.com/) и [Devdocs](https://devdocs.io/) по моему мнению лучшие ресурсы по разным языкам программирования

###### C#

1. [Metanit](https://metanit.com/sharp/)
2. [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/)
3. [Professor Web](https://professorweb.ru/)

##### C

1. [Metanit](https://metanit.com/cpp/c/)
2. [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/c-language/c-language-reference?view=msvc-170)
3. [Devdocs](https://devdocs.io/c/)

##### C++

1. [Metanit](https://metanit.com/cpp/tutorial/)
2. [Devdocs](https://devdocs.io/cpp/)

##### Python

1. [Справочная документация по языку Python3](https://docs-python.ru/)
2. [Самоучитель Python](https://pythonworld.ru/samouchitel-python)
3. [Digitology](https://digitology.tech/docs/python_3/index.html)
4. [Metanit](https://metanit.com/python/tutorial/)

##### Java

[Про Java](http://pr0java.blogspot.com/p/java.html) большой сборник ссылок на полезные ресурсы

##### JavaScript

1. [Современный учебник по JavaScript](https://learn.javascript.ru/)
2. [Справочник по JavaScript](https://devdocs.io/javascript/)
3. [mdn web-docs JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript)

##### PHP

1. [Документация PHP](https://www.php.net/docs.php)
2. [Metanit](https://metanit.com/php/)

##### Perl

1. [Perldoc Browser](https://perldoc.perl.org/)
2. [Учебник Perl по-русски](https://ru.perlmaven.com/perl-tutorial)
3. [Perl 5 документация](https://perl5doc.ru/)

Comment: Да, точно, Devdocks... крайне благодарен за помощь)