# Книги и учебные ресурсы по Fortran

Tags: книги, faq, fortran

Рекомендуемая литература, статьи и документация по [Fortran](https://fortran-lang.org/) ([fortran](/questions/tagged/fortran)).

##### Формат ответов с книгами

> Название книги(год) - описание, от автор - ссылка(и)

Для переведённых изданий:

> Переведённое Название книги (Оригинальное Название книги) - переведённое описание (оригинальное описание), от ориг. автор (перевод от автор перевода) - ссылка(и)

##### Формат ответов со статьями или файлами/документами (по типу doc, docx, pdf, djvu)

> Название
> описание(если есть), год,
>
> ссылка(и)

###### Для отвечающих

- Не создавайте новых ответов, редактируйте существующий.
- Не размещайте ссылки на нелегальный контент вроде торрент-трекеров.
- Сохраняйте разделение по категориям (Книги / Статьи).
- Нумеруйте каждый добавленный материал (1.x для статей, 2.x для книг)

---

> Данный перечень входит в поддерживаемый сообществом [Сборник учебных ресурсов по программированию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683).

Comment: Поверьте, у Fortran есть значительно больше версий. Предположу, что несколько десятков. Например, масса версий типа Fortran-CERN, Fortran-Дубна и других. Вы уверены, что они вам все нужны:-)?  Если интересно, вот вам ссылка на Дубну, например:  <http://publ.lib.ru/ARCHIVES/B/''Bibliotechka_programmista''/_''BP''.html#0025>. Не удивительно, что на русском. Если там будут рекомендации по изготовлению перфокарт, то не удивляйтесь, передовой ведь метод был ввода кода в машину:-)

Comment: Почитайте советские институтские учебники 70x-80х годов (их не должно быть много, а наиболее приличными должны быть по Fortran-77). Основной всплеск Fortran был тогда, и в учебниках должны быть списки подобных версий.

Comment: Кажется, поворотную врсию -- f90 (собственно, это стандартное расширение для файлов с исходным кодом для `gfortran` (как я понял, просматривая quck turorial по вашей первой ссылке)) вы в своем перечне версий упустили. Да, язык здорово изменился за 40 лет. Я даже не уловил, добавили ли в современном фортране рекурсию (косвенно на такую возможность намекают замечания об освобождении  локальных для процедур данных в том же tutorial) / И мне кажется, списки литературы надо разделить на 2 раздела. Первый -- исторический, до f90 (завершается 77-м), а второй -- современный (наверное основной тут f95)

Comment: Да, гугл подсказывает, что начиная с f90 рекурсия есть. Кстати, [вот это руководство](https://coderlessons.com/tutorials/kompiuternoe-programmirovanie/vyuchit-fortran/fortran-kratkoe-rukovodstvo) мне показалось толковым

Comment: стандартный пакет в линуксе:  gcc13-fortran  | The GNU Fortran Compiler and Support Files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Статьи и файлы

#### 1.0 Статья с официального сайта:

###### Quickstart tutorial

This quickstart tutorial gives an overview of the Fortran programming language and its syntax for common structured programming concepts including: types, variables, arrays, control flow and functions. **2020**

https://fortran-lang.org/learn/quickstart

#### 1.1 Не официальный туториал:

###### FORTRAN Tutorial - Free Guide to Programming Fortran 90/95

This FORTRAN study guide is a "hands on" introduction to programming using FORTRAN. **2011**

https://www.fortrantutorial.com/index.php

PDF Формат:
https://www.fortrantutorial.com/documents/IntroductionToFTN95.pdf

#### 1.2 RIP Tutorial:

###### Getting started with Fortran

**2018**

https://riptutorial.com/fortran

#### 1.3 Tutorials Point:

###### Fortran Tutorial

This tutorial is designed for the readers who wish to learn the basics of Fortran. **~2000**

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/fortran/index.htm

PDF Формат: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/fortran/fortran_tutorial.pdf

#### 1.4 EbookFoundation

###### free-programming-books(GitHub)

**2020**

  [github.com/EbookFoundation/free-programming-books/](https://github.com/EbookFoundation/free-programming-books/blob/main/books/free-programming-books-langs.md#fortran)
- [Exploring Modern Fortran Basics](https://www.manning.com/books/exploring-modern-fortran-basics)
- [Fortran 90 Tutorial](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/fortran.html)
- [Fortran 90 Tutorial](https://web.stanford.edu/class/me200c/tutorial_90/)(2)
- [Fortran's information & resources](https://www.fortranplus.co.uk/fortran-information/)
- [FORTRAN Performance Tuning co-Guide (1998)](https://www.ibiblio.org/pub/languages/fortran/unct.html)
- [Introduction to Fortran](https://qc2-teaching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming.html)
- [Modern Fortran in Science and Technology](https://modern-fortran-in-science-and-technology.readthedocs.io/en/latest)
- [Modern Fortran Tutorial](https://masuday.github.io/fortran_tutorial/)
- [Professional Programmer’s Guide to Fortran77 (2005)](https://www.star.le.ac.uk/~cgp/prof77.pdf)
- [Self Study Guide 2: Programming in Fortran 95](http://www.mrao.cam.ac.uk/~rachael/compphys/SelfStudyF95.pdf)
- [User Notes On Fortran Programming (UNFP): An open cooperative practical guide (1998)](https://www.ibiblio.org/pub/languages/fortran/)

#### 1.5 GFortranStandards

###### Fortran Standards Documents

Draft (unofficial) versions of the various recent Fortran standards and corrigenda are available from the [J3 website](//j3-fortran.org/), the [WG5 website](//wg5-fortran.org/), in various formats. **2006-2022**

https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranStandards

#### 1.6 CoderLessons.com

###### Фортран – Краткое руководство

**2019**

https://coderlessons.com/tutorials/kompiuternoe-programmirovanie/vyuchit-fortran/fortran-kratkoe-rukovodstvo

### Книги

**2.0 *Алгоритмический язык фортран (Фортран-Дубна)*** (1976) — В книге дано подробное описание языка фортран, одного из самых распространенных языков программирования на электронных вычислительных машинах, от В. Я. Карпова — [publ.lib.ru/ARCHIVES/B/''Bibliotechka_programmista''/_''BP''.html#0025](http://publ.lib.ru/ARCHIVES/B/%27%27Bibliotechka_programmista%27%27/_%27%27BP%27%27.html#0025) ([Файл](http://publ.lib.ru/ARCHIVES/B/%27%27Bibliotechka_programmista%27%27/Karpov_V.Ya._Algoritmicheskiy_yazyk_Fortran_(Fortran-Dubna).(1976).[djv-fax].zip))

**2.1 *Ошибки-ловушки при программировании на фортране.*** (1987) — Основное содержание книги составляют задачи, цель которых - поиск ошибок в приведенных программах на фортране, от Г. К. Воронина, М. М. Комарова, В. С. Брошевского — [publ.lib.ru/ARCHIVES/B/''Bibliotechka_programmista''/_''BP''.html#0005](http://publ.lib.ru/ARCHIVES/B/%27%27Bibliotechka_programmista%27%27/_%27%27BP%27%27.html#0005) ([Файл](http://publ.lib.ru/ARCHIVES/B/%27%27Bibliotechka_programmista%27%27/Borovin_G.K..._Oshibki-lovushki_pri_programmirovanii_na_fortrane.(1987).[djv-fax].zip))

**2.2 *Основы Фортрана*** (1972) — Книга знакомит читателя с самым, распространенным в настоящее время языком программирования для вычислительных машин, от Ю. А. Первин — [publ.lib.ru/ARCHIVES/B/''Bibliotechka_programmista''/_''BP''.html#0024](http://publ.lib.ru/ARCHIVES/B/%27%27Bibliotechka_programmista%27%27/_%27%27BP%27%27.html#0024) ([Файл](http://publ.lib.ru/ARCHIVES/B/%27%27Bibliotechka_programmista%27%27/Pervin_Yu.A._Osnovy_Fortrana.(1972).[djv-fax].zip))

**2.3 *Программирование на языке фортран*** (1976) — В книге излагаются основы программирования на алгоритмическом языке фортран и автокоде madlen для БЭСМ-6, от А. И. Салтыкова, Г. И. Макаренко — [publ.lib.ru/ARCHIVES/B/''Bibliotechka_programmista''/_''BP''.html#0024](http://publ.lib.ru/ARCHIVES/B/%27%27Bibliotechka_programmista%27%27/_%27%27BP%27%27.html#0039) ([Файл](http://publ.lib.ru/ARCHIVES/B/%27%27Bibliotechka_programmista%27%27/Saltykov_A.I..._Programmirovanie_na_yazyke_Fortran.(1976).[djv-fax].zip))

**2.4 *Современный Фортран*** (2004) — Книга является пособием по изучению языка Фортран. Последовательно излагается синтаксис языка, рассматривается реализация основных алгоритмических конструкций., от С. А. Немюгин, О. Стесик — [publ.lib.ru/ARCHIVES/S/''Samouchitel'''/_''SU''.html#0005](http://publ.lib.ru/ARCHIVES/S/%27%27Samouchitel%27%27%27/_%27%27SU%27%27.html#0005) ([Файл](http://publ.lib.ru/ARCHIVES/S/%27%27Samouchitel%27%27%27/Nemnyugin_S.A..._Sovremennyy_Fortran.(2004).[djv-fax].zip))

**2.5 *Курс программирования на ФОРТРАНе-IV (A course on programming in FORTRAN IV)*** (1972) — Книга предназначена для изучения основ программирования на ФОРТРАНе-IV, который широко используется в сфере научных и инженерно-технических вычислений (*Алтернативное описание отсутствует*), от Valerie J. Calderbank (Автор перевода В. С. Першенкова) — [publ.lib.ru/ARCHIVES/B/''Biblioteka_po_avtomatike''/_''BpA''*0500-0599*.html#0552](http://publ.lib.ru/ARCHIVES/B/%27%27Biblioteka_po_avtomatike%27%27/_%27%27BpA%27%27_0500-0599_.html#0552) ([Файл](http://publ.lib.ru/ARCHIVES/B/%27%27Biblioteka_po_avtomatike%27%27/%27%27Biblioteka_po_avtomatike%27%27,v.0552.(1976).[djv-fax].zip))

##### Дополнительные инструменты:

- [Конвертор из DJVU на PDF](//djvu2pdf.com/)
- [Песочница Fortran](//play.fortran-lang.org/)

Comment: соблюдай все-таки формат, который сам в вопросе указал :) _Название книги(Name of book) - описание(description), от author(перевод от автор перевода) - ссылка(и)_

Comment: @Grundy Для книг формат исправлен, а вот для статей есть отдельный формат.(см. в вопросе)

Comment: ок. на гитхабе в оформлении указаны авторы, поэтому казалось, что это именно книги.

Comment: *"Fortran Tutorial .... год неизвестен"*. Судя по [истории g95](http://progopedia.ru/implementation/g95/) и тексту туториала, он был создан в начале 2000-x / @NNL993, imho не мешает пронумеровать все книги-тексты (для удобства ссылок на них  в комментариях)