# Книги и учебные ресурсы по Godot и GDScript

Tags: книги, faq, godot, gdscript

В этом вопросе собирается литература по Godot и GDScript

Формат:

> Имя Фамилия — «Название книги целиком и полностью», ГГГГ г..

Формат для переведенной литературы:

> Имя Фамилия (Name Surname) — «Название книги целиком и полностью», ГГГГ перевода ("Full name of the book", YYYY )

- Не создавайте новых ответов — редактируйте этот.
- Не размещайте ссылки на нелегальный контент вроде торрент-трекеров.
- Старайтесь сохранять разделение по категориям.

---

> Данный перечень входит в поддерживаемый сообществом [Сборник учебных ресурсов по программированию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683).

Comment: Хм.. А ответ с книгами где?

Comment: @Qwertiy Я уже понял свою ошибку. Просто я не создал ответ потому-что не знаю ни одной книги по Godot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Официальные ресурсы:

- Документация по Godot на [английском](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/) и [русском](https://docs.godotengine.org/ru/stable/)

---

## Видео ресурсы:

- [Godot Basics](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQl2eWiUO8_K2fNv6Y1s6wv4Yr-fzXCXc) от @FinePointCGI
- [GDQuest](https://www.gdquest.com/) - большой ресурс по Godot, есть у них платные курсы, но очень много и свободно доступных ресурсов, в т.ч. на [GitHub](https://github.com/GDQuest), [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/c/gdquest).

---

## Онлайн курсы:

- Godot для абсолютных новичков (платный) доступен на [stepik](https://stepik.org/course/123947/promo?search=2422346331) и [udemy](https://www.udemy.com/course/ru-godot/).

---

## Книги:

- Patrick Felicia — «Godot from Zero to Proficiency», 2022. ([Серия](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08YQK1WCB) из пяти книг)

---

## Чаты и каналы:

- [Godot на русском](https://vk.com/godot_rus_docs)