# Как решить задачу в Godot не используя обьекты классов?

Tags: c#, godot

Суть в чем, у меня есть класс:

```cs
public class Block
{
    [Export]
    public Vector2 coord = new Vector2(0,0);
    [Export]
    public bool isOpen = false;
    [Export]
    public String[] nameTraps;
    [Export]
    public String[] otherSwithes;
}
```

Скрипт на нод:

```cs
public class SwitchHandler : RigidBody2D
{        
    [Export]
    public Вlock[] infoOutage; //Так не получается использовать список чтобы в редакторе редактировать Resource тоже не вариант 
}
```

У меня есть нод кнопки куда подключаю скрипт со списком Block[] Если бы я был в юнити проблем никаких я бы просто в игровом обьекте редактировал этот список классов. Но в Godot я этого сделать не могу. Как мне выйти из ситуации наиболее удобным способом, Resource использовать не вариант, у меня кнопок много я же не буду под каждую файл resource создавать?

Comment: Не совсем понятна суть, вы хотите редактировать этот список через интерфейс редактора или о чём речь?

Comment: Ну я хочу список обьектов в обьекте и чтобы этот список можно было редактировать. Счас дополню наверно.

Comment: Кстати можете прислать книгу или учебный ресурс по которому вы изучали Godot [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1499440/507516).

Comment: Пока только официальная дока (https://docs.godotengine.org/ru/stable/index.html) и чат gpt,  там кстати 4 вышел. Книги смотрел что есть но не читал.