# Не могу найти хороший и понятный учебник по GDscript

Tags: godot, gdscript

Я хочу серьёзно заниматься программированием. Выбрал движок "Godot Engine v3.5.2". Теперь мне нужно выучить GDscript, а как это сделать не знаю. Возможно кто-то мог бы посоветовать какую то литературу или еще чего?
Заранее спасибо!

Я пробовал смотреть уроки по созданию игр с нуля, но убедился что нужно учить язык программирования. Также читал Godot Docs но лично мне не очень понятно. Больше кроме платных курсов найти мне нечего не удалось.
(проходить платные курсы не имею возможности).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1499310/507426

Comment: Привет. Для этого нужно понимать базовые принципы создания приложений на Python. Оф. документацию можно найти здесь: https://docs.godotengine.org/ru/stable/. Когда-то баловался с этим движком и считаю его довольно мощным, документации вполне достаточно, чтобы сделать что-нибудь своё

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Godot и GDScript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1499310/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-godot-%d0%b8-gdscript)

Comment: @PetrAbdulin интересно что на этом вопросе 2 за, а на моём 0. (мой это "Книги и учебные ресурсы по Godot и GDScript")

Answer (score 0):

GDScript язык созданный специально для Godot и по нему скорее всего не существует отдельных книг или курсов как таковых, ну кроме собственно родной документации, уж очень он получается нишевый. В любом случае суть в том, что учить в отрыве от самого движка его будет затруднительно, но может это и хорошо? В смысле что есть мотивация.

Также он немного похож на язык программирования Python, который очень популярен и можно найти много ресурсов в т.ч. и на русском языке. Для него есть и библиотека PyGame на которой можно делать игры, чтобы не было скучно учить.

Не вижу ничего плохого в освоении Godot и одновременном изучении языка GDScript, но конечно хорошо бы освоить хотя бы базовые вещи: переменные, функции, объекты, условные переходы, циклы, массивы и т.п. иначе на первых порах будет тяжело понять даже базовые мануалы, где всё таки предполагается знание базовых концепций программирования.

И небольшое замечание, основная версия движка уже перевалила за 4.0, при этом были сделаны некоторые заметные изменения, я не знаю по какой причине вы упомянули именно 3.5.2, но я бы рекомендовал работать именно на текущей - 4.1+.