# Делаю диалог на godot3 с помощью ассета dialogic 1.5 нужно чтобы диалог начинался только при пересечении area2D

Tags: godot, dialog

Далаю 2д игру в godot3 для создания диалогов использую dialodic 1.5 в игре при заходе в сцену с диалогом диалог начинается сразу, но мне нужно чтобы он запускался только при входе в area2D. Как это можно осуществить?

Скриншот программы с проектом:

[image: Скриншот программы с проектом]

И код в виде текста:

```
extends Area2D


var entered = false

func _on_Area2D_body_entered(body: PhysicsBody2D):
    entered = true


func _on_Area2D_body_exited(body):
    entered = false


func _process(delta):
    if entered == true:
        if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_accept"):
            get_tree().change_scene("res://world 2.tscn")
```

Пытался вызвать сцену диалога с помощью данного кода.

Я начинающий поэтому в gdscript не шарю

Comment: [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/385375)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю точно в чём у вас проблема, но я рекомендую переименовать `world 2.tscn` в `world_2.tscn` (убрать пробелы). Также я сильно изменил ваш код:

```
extends Area2D


func _on_Area2D_body_entered(body):
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_accept"):
        get_tree().change_scene("res://world_2.tscn")
```

Но не на 100% уверен что так правильно.

И кстати прежде чем писать игры хорошо-бы научиться GDScript ([Книги и учебные ресурсы по Godot и GDScript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1499310/)).