# Книги и учебные ресурсы на тему науки о данных (data science)

Tags: книги, анализ-данных, faq

В этом вопросе собирается литература на тему *науки о данных* (*data science*)

Формат:

> Имя Фамилия — «Название книги целиком и полностью», ГГГГ г..

Формат для переведенной литературы:

> Имя Фамилия (Name Surname) — «Название книги целиком и полностью», ГГГГ перевода ("Full name of the book", YYYY )

- Не создавайте новых ответов — редактируйте этот.
- Не размещайте ссылки на нелегальный контент вроде торрент-трекеров.
- Старайтесь сохранять разделение по категориям.

---

> Данный перечень входит в поддерживаемый сообществом [Сборник учебных ресурсов по программированию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Книги

- Дж. Вандер Плас (Jake Wander Plas) — «Python для сложных задач: наука о данных и машинное обучение», 2020 ("Python Data Science Handbook: Essential Tools for Working with Data", 2017)
- Джоэл Грас (Joel Grus) — «Data Science: Наука о данных с нуля», 2022  ("Data Science from Scratch: First Principles with Python", 2019)
- Себастьян Рашка Вахид Мирджалили (Sebastian Raschka, Vahid Mirjalili) - "Машинное и глубокое обучение с использованием Python, scikit-learn и TensorFlow2", 2020 ("Machine Learning and Deep Learning with Python, scikit-learn, and TensorFlow2")

---

## Онлайн курсы:

- "Анализ данных" - stepik: https://stepik.org/course/57623/promo
- "Data Science с Глебом Михайловым" - stepik: https://stepik.org/course/113596/promo
- "Machine Learning" author: AndrewNg- coursera:
  https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning

---

## Чаты и каналы

- ["Data Science Chat"](https://telegram.me/datasciencechat)

Comment: [free-programming-books](https://github.com/EbookFoundation/free-programming-books/blob/main/books/free-programming-books-subjects.md#data-science)

Comment: [Дж. Вандер Плас (Jake Wander Plas) — «Python для сложных задач: наука о данных и машинное обучение»](https://codernet.ru/books/python/python_dlya_slognih_zadach_nauka_o_dannih_i_mashinnoe_obychenie_vander/)