# Задачи по JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pure_js

***Добрый день!*** || ***утро!*** || ***вечер!***

**Часть первая - "ВСТУПИТЕЛЬНО-ПОВЕСТВОВАТЕЛЬНАЯ"** (Необязательна к прочтению)

Активно **изучаю JavaScript**. Это мой первый язык программирования. Взялся-было за jQuery, но решил отложить, так как, не хочу быть кодером, который знает несколько событий, умеет подключать плагины, но при этом, понятия не имеет о массивах, циклах, объектах и т.д. В общем, решил подойти к изучению основательно, чтобы в последствии не мучить глупыми вопросами, таких замечательных товарищей как @Deonis, @lampa, @Barton, @Spectre, @Rules и других не менее замечательных товарищей. Прошу прощения, если вдруг забыл упомянуть кого-то из тех, кто мне когда-либо помогал.

Мои знания на данный момент:

- HTML // хорошо (стремлюсь к совершенству);
- CSS // хорошо (стремлюсь к совершенству);
- JS // чуть > 0 (стрем...);

---

**Часть вторая - "ВОПРОСИТЕЛЬНАЯ"** (Рекомендуется к прочтению)

Основные источники по которым изучаю JS^

- javascript.ru
- JavaScript. Подробное руководство - Дэвид Флэнаган.

Оба источника хороши, но **маловато заданий на закрепление изученного материала**.

В настоящий момент, мной изучены следующие темы:

- Переменные, операторы...
- Условные операторы: if, '?';
- Циклы while, for;
- Конструкция switch;
- Функции;

В связи с малым количеством практических заданий в выше указанных источниках и неутешительными результатами в поисковых выдачах Google & Yandex, **обращаюсь к Вам** - *помогите кто чем может, подкиньте идей*, а то у меня что-то с фантазией проблема...

Особенно здорово было-бы увидеть **задачи, соотносящиеся по сложности с моими знаниями** (изученным мной материалам).
Интересуют задачи **направленные на практическое применение**, приведу парочку примеров таких задач, которые были мной найдены и выполнены:

1. [Раскрашивание таблицы](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/5wufU/)
2. [Создание элемента и добавление его в DOM](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/Fc6tn/)

---

**Часть третья - "ЗАКЛЮЧИТЕЛЬНО-УВЕСЕЛИТЕЛЬНАЯ"** (обязательна к прочтению)

[image]

---

Прошу прощения за много букв.

Comment: Практика легка, теория тяжела.

Попробуйте вот [это](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2628672/276994), посмотрите, откроете ли вы для себя что-то новое.

Comment: Практика легка, теория тяжела.

@VladD, согласен с Вами, но хочется совмещать теорию и практику. Думаю это даст лучший результат, нежели изучение только теории, без практических занятий.
  
    посмотрите, откроете ли вы для себя что-то новое

Да, еще открывать и открывать...

Comment: О, тогда попробуйте поотвечать на вопросы по js тут и на stackoverflow. На все! Увидите, как вырастет ваш уровень. (И уровень владения английским тоже.)

Comment: @VladD, спасибо за ценные советы.

Comment: @Astor: пожалуйста)

Comment: подобные вопросы -- просто привлечение к себе внимания. Все учебники у тебя есть, просто выбери любую задачу и решай.

Comment: @Astor Ну раз что-то изучено - значит уже хорошо :) 

Классика - напиши калькулятор. Дальше попробуй сделать снежинки, дада :) Потом можно поработать с текстом - написать простенький текстовый редактор. 

Для повышения скилла по jQuery - попробуй напиши "Рабочий стол". Со всеми плюшками виндового рабочего стола. Охват функций достаточно большой.

Comment: @Vladimir Gordeev, думать так - Ваше право. Каждый смотрит со своей колокольни.

Я думаю, что ответы на данный вопрос, будут интересны многим людям, начинающим изучать JS.

Comment: @lampa как вы угадали ? :) Первое что я сделал - калькулятор - потом крестики нолики...

Comment: >Я думаю, что ответы на данный вопрос, будут интересны многим людям, начинающим изучать JS.

и всё равно каждый из них создаст такой же вопрос

Comment: @Spectre +1 :)

Comment: @Spectre, то есть я не первый?

Comment: @Astor вопросы типа:
> Как стать профи в <чём-то>?
> Что делать дальше?

и 

>Какая книга по <чему нибудь> лучшая?

задаются часто и настолько надоели старожилам что они уже задавали вопрос о создании (как на [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/ "Сайт типа Хэшкода'а") ) базы книг и т.п. отсортированной по категориям уровням и с оценками и комментами куда посылают с вопросами как у вас :)

Comment: w3school.com весьма полезен. Но он на аглицком

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Мои знания на данный момент:
>
> HTML // хорошо (стремлюсь к
> совершенству); CSS // хорошо
> (стремлюсь к совершенству); JS // чуть
>
> > 0 (стрем...);

Вот тут мне стало интересно, но это скорее именно интерес.

Ты хочешь кем стать? Верстальщиком или программистом? или как сейчас модно web-мастер?

HTML+CSS знать в совершенстве программисту web'a зачем? Никогда я к этому не стремился и не буду. Есть же верстальщики, которые знают всю эту кухню раз в 100 лучше меня.

На базовом уровне знать можно, основы, ну и слепить сверстать какую-то мелочь - это конечно будет плюсом, но знать в совершенстве не за чем.

А про задачи возьми напиши какую-нибудь большую и красивую форму, и навешивай понемногу на неё обработчики, события. Ну и смотри как она будет разрастаться и работать.

Маленькие задачи обычно дают в школах, колледжах и универах. Не видел ни одного ответа, чтобы тут на хэшкоде кто-то давал маленькие задачи по запросу.

А вообще если уж очень хочется, порыскай тут же на форуме вопросы по теле JS и реши те задачи(вопросы) которые уже тут описаны. Это и будет тебе ХоумВорк!

Comment: @Shrek, спасибо за ответ. На Ваш вопрос отвечу так - хочу стать очень хорошим frontend'ом, который знает все нюансы и тонкости тех технологий, с которыми он работает.

Comment: @Astor frontend - так все-таки верстальщик? ибо html+css+js это именно это.

У меня просто не поворачивается назвать программистом верстальщика т.к. очень узкий спектр работы у него, но здесь он может быть лучшим в своем деле и я очень сильно уважаю Именно ХОРОШИХ верстальщиков.

Comment: @Shrek, да, ты прав. Именно такая связка меня интересует. К этому в данный момент я и стремлюсь - хочу быть лучшим в своем деле.

Comment: Ну тогда ты в правильном направлении. Удачи :)

Comment: Спасибо. Приятно было пообщаться.

Comment: Хм, наоборот советую эти три вещи (html+css+js) изучать вместе. Изучил технологии и пили бабла в 2 раза больше, уехоу!

Answer (score 2):

Ну если DOM вам знаком, попробуйте написать календарик, всплывающий возле input. Причём input'ов таких на странице может быть множество и каждый помнит свою дату. При это в реале сам календарик только один.

Задача интересная, ручаюсь, а так же пригодная для практического применения в будующем.

Comment: @Gedweb, спасибо, но к сожалению, для выполнения предложенной Вами задачи, знаний пока маловато, хотелось бы изучать более поэтапно, - от простого к сложному.

Answer (score 2):

Если с пониманием английского в порядке, попробуйте [это](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript). Теория подается с интерактивными задачками и расчитано вроде на изучение с нуля.

Comment: @gcoder, спасибо. Интересно будет посмотреть...

Answer (score 1):

Насчёт календарика, непонятно зачем велосипед изобретать это в UI есть datepicker ...

Насчёт задач посоветую начать асинхронную архитектуру изучать. Ajax откроет много нового и перспективного... только не усложняйте себе жизнь prototype'ом

По асинхронке.. попробуйте написать чат ... очень веселая и практически бесконечная в плане нововведений задачка... я писал в своё время... но там развитие остановилось ибо работа дом работа дом ну так у всех я думаю... за самообразование современные работодатели не особо то платят.

jQuery советую всё-таки начать... конструкции те же ... а лишнего кода минимум.. + победа в кроссбраузерности.

Его главное не бояться.

Для фронтенда так же добавлю что стоит почитать о шаблонизаторах и фреймворках Smarty ну и Symfony. Взять на вооружение пару CMS (пригодится) ну если совсем уж серверная часть не интересна то jQuery будет единственным советом...

Comment: > на счет календарика непонятно зачем велосипед изобретать

В данном конкретном случае - это не изобретение велосипеда, а практика.

Comment: @Deonis: пришёл сюда, чтобы оставить такой же комментарий :)

Answer (score 1):

вот задачка от меня :)

1) создай на html-е табличку

2) при нажатии на ячейку заменяй текст ячейки на input с текстом ячейки, а при нажатии на enter или выходе фокуса с input'а изменяй текст на новый. как вариант при нажатии на esc введенные данные отменяются.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы посоветовал (правда слегка устаревшую и не "повёрнутую" на программинге) книгу

> Пол Вилтон Джереми МакПик JavaScript Руководство программиста (Beginning JavaScript 3rd edition) именно с неё и начинал а потом уже [двинулся дальше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/148086/%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-javascript)...

***PS***: В этой книге после каждой главы даются задания на закрепление и в конце книги есть ответы...
***PPS:***  А ещё предлагается по окончанию книги написать игру-викторину TrivaQuiz (и писать вы её будете прямо во время прочтения глав). Я думаю как раз то что вам нужно...

Comment: книги с ответами.

Прикольно, и на работу бы еще брали также, с приготовленной заранее зарплатой и решенными задачами. Все бы жили тогда хорошо.

Comment: @Shrek а вы считаете в C++ Primer нет задач на закрепление и Ответов в конце книги :) Такая и должна быть хорошая книга imho...

Comment: @Rules, прошу заметить, что мой вопрос был - не какая книга лучшая и не как стать профи, а скорее просьба покинуть идей, для закрепления изученного материала.

Ваши идеи с калькулятором и крестиками/ноликами хороши, но к сожалению, я пока не владею такими знаниями, чтобы реализовать подобные задачи. Может подкините идейку соответствующую моим знаниям на данный момент(указаны в вопросе)? 

Буду Вам очень признателен.

Comment: А вы смотрели указанную в моём ответе книгу? - она как раз для вас... А насчёт заданий сделайте например свой сайт на бесплатном хостинге например [вот мой проэкт](http://webwin.hostoi.com/) на хостинге [000webhost.com](http://www.000webhost.com/) нажмёте там Sign Up и Free gosting зарегистрируете, найдёте FTP менеджер например FileZilla FTP Client и загрузите туда чё душе угодно или используйте [Denwer](http://www.denwer.ru/ "Dжентельменский Nабор WEb Rазработчика").

Comment: Я так начал, создав на narod.yandex.ru свой сайт про компы На своём сайте можете сделать например часики тикающие вверху страницы и воображение короче само придёт! Всё равно вам рано или поздно придётся знать "что такое веб-сервер и с чем его едят".. :) Не будете же вы пользоваться JsFiddle всегда :)

Comment: И ещё я бы настоятельно порекомендовал Learn English сами видите как обстоят дела. И кстати лучше вам наверное с Denwer начать [вот статья про него](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80_%28%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%29) а потом уже на настоящий хостинг пойдёте...

Comment: @Rules, спасибо.

С хостингом проблем нет. Английский в процессе изучения...
Книгу, которую Вы посоветовали, - не найти... на Озоне нет, rutracker тоже не спасает...